# Do Swiss banks have the right to demand seeing a visa for a foreign country?

Tags: banking, switzerland

A friend who is a Swiss citizen and resident of Switzerland has a checking account with a Swiss bank. Because of a stay in the US, he was asked to file a "Status Declaration Form for Individuals" confirming that he is not a US resident.
In addition to many more documents including tax returns, the bank asks to see his US visa.

Does a Swiss bank have the legal right to request seeing a visa for a foreign country, and if so under which paragraph of which law?

Comment: If they are a US resident it imposes reporting requirements on the bank (since 2010). It has become harder for a US citizen to open an account in Europe as a result. This also impacts those who have worked in the US.

Comment: I submit that the issue is if a law gives your friend the right to not comply.

Comment: @TigerGuy surely the bank has the right to ask and the friend has the right not to comply.  The real question is what actions the bank has the right to take (or indeed the obligation) of the friend exercises his right not to comply.

Comment: @phoog the bank may also have the right to not do business with the person if they do not comply

Comment: @TigerGuy that is exactly my point.  They may in fact have an obligation not to do business with the friend if he doesn't comply.

Comment: The issue is probably international tax compliance. U.S. residents are subject to U.S. income tax on their worldwide income. If you've been in the U.S., a review of the visa is a quick way to show that the person was only there temporarily and not a resident. Not clear why the friend would have a problem with sharing that with their bank unless they are lying to their bank for the purposes of tax evasion.

Comment: @ohwilleke possession of a visa does not preclude admission in another immigration status, which may be relevant to the substantial presence test (some statuses are exempt for that purpose).  It is fairly strong evidence that the bearer is not a US national or permanent resident, however, which is also relevant to tax residence because nationals and permanent residents are tax residents regardless of where they spend their time.  One possible reason for not wanting to show the visa is that there may be no visa (Swiss citizens can use the visa waiver program for visits up to 90 days in length).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes

The relevant Swiss law is known as the [FATCA Agreement](https://www.sif.admin.ch/sif/en/home/bilateral-relations/countries/united-states-america/fatca-agreement.html) and has been in force since 30/6/2014. FATCA stands for the Foreign Account Tax Compliance Act, a unilateral set of US regulations that applies worldwide for all countries. It requires foreign financial institutions to disclose information on US accounts to the Internal Revenue Service or levy a high tax.

At the moment, Switzerland uses the "Model 2" agreement with the USA, which requires the consent of the US taxpayer or an administrative request by the IRS. There are plans to move to the "Model 1" arrangement, which uses automatic data sharing, but the timeline is uncertain.

The bank is required to verify that your friend is not a US tax resident, and the visa is one of the pieces of evidence they need. Your friend can, of course, refuse to produce it. The bank can then either refuse to do business with them, or treat them as though they *are* a US tax resident and withhold the required tax until such time as they prove they are not.

Comment: Relevant to the question: some statuses carry with them an exemption to the "substantial presence test" and others do not, although the possession of a visa in a given class does not actually show that the bearer was _admitted_ in that class.  There ought to be other ways to prove nonresidence, and in fact some of those ways, such as a comprehensive listing of entry and exit records showing the immigration status, would be more conclusive than the mere possession of a visa.

Comment: Since in reality they don't want a US visa, but evidence that you are not a US resident, would applying for a visa and having it refused for some other reason count as evidence? Or a visa waiver? I have one of those, and my wife has one that is expired because she renewed her passport.